# fail to update data into database

Tags: codeigniter

Controller
function edit($RegNo){
$data['row'] = $this->ManageTr`enter code here`ansfers->GetById($RegNo);
$this->load->view('admin/transferupdate', $data);
}

```
enter code here
    public function update($RegNo){ 
    $this->ManageT`enter code here`ransfers->update($RegNo);
    redirect('admin/ManageTransfer/transfer');
}
```

Model
function GetById($RegNo){
return $this->db->get_where('user_transfer', array('RegNo' => $RegNo ))->row();

```
}

function update($RegNo){

    $arr['School'] = $this->input->post('School');
    $arr['Date'] = $this->input->post('Date');
    $arr['RegNo'] = $this->input->post('RegNo');
    $arr['Class'] = $this->input->post('Class');
    $arr['New'] = $this->input->post('New');
    $arr['Reason'] = $this->input->post('Reason');
    $arr['UserId'] = $this->input->post('UserId');
    $arr['Status'] = $this->input->post('Status');

    $this->db->where(array('RegNo' => $RegNo));
    $this->db->update('user_transfer', $arr);
    
}
```

View

RegNo);?>">

error occur
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: admin/transferupdate.php

Line Number: 12

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$this->db->where(array('RegNo' => $RegNo));
```

like this

```
$this->db->where('RegNo', $RegNo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function update($RegNo){

    $arr= array();
    $post_data=$this->input->post();
    $arr=(
        'School' => $post_data['School'],
        'Date' => $post_data['Date'],
        'RegNo' => $post_data['RegNo'],
        'Class' => $post_data['Class'],
        'New' => $post_data['New'],
        'Reason' => $post_data['Reason'],
        'UserId' => $post_data['UserId'],
        'Status' => $post_data['Status']
    );

    $this->db->where('RegNo', $RegNo);
    $this->db->update('user_transfer', $arr);
    
}
```